# Highcharts : xAxis in datetime format (00:00 - 24:00) and n series with n interval in datetime format

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I will try to explain better, starting with this image, that should make you understand better what i want to display in the graph. (the data will be taken from a database, but that's not important)

[image]

For every single day (and this graph represents a single day) I would like to see on the chart all the users (at most are 5-6) who have made at least one "action". These "actions" have a **start time** and an **end time**.

In this case, users are the series.And every series is a list of intervals (of time) of all actions made by the user on that day.

Example of series of a user who has made three actions on this day (yes, the time stamp will be multiplied by 1000)

```
[["1430362800","1430366400"],["1430391600","1430398800"],["1430424000","1430425800"]]
```

To view on the x-axis the interval 00:00 - 24:00 i will do

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickInterval: 3600 * 1000
}
```

Each horizontal line must be a user. To do that I should set the maximum and minimum of the y-axis. And , for example , if the users are 3 i'll do something like that (i will add only one axis, and the value (y) of each user must be 1,2,3...).

```
chart.addAxis({
    min: 1,
    max : 3,
    ceiling:1,
    tickInterval: 1,
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
             if (this.value <= 3){
                  return "";
             }else{
                  return null;
             }
         }
    }
});
```

The problem is that i don't know which type of chart used to display this type of data. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a GANT chart (horizontal barchart meaning the yAxis will become time) with another yAxis (which will be xAxis really) which will be line/scatter chart for user count.. All over the xAxis (really yAxis) of time ! Unless iv'e misunderstood..

Comment: This is gantt type of chart, please visit our implementations of that, [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart)

Comment: It seems to be an excellent starting point, thanks